# Fail to load nodelet

Tags: ros, kinect, roslaunch, nodelet, ccny-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ROS and i'm trying to generate a very simple map of the room that i'm in with my Kinect.
I am using ccny_rgbd_tools but I reach a point that gives me nodelets related errors...
I used the command roslaunch ccny_openni_launch openni.launch

```
process[camera_rgb_frame_tf-5]: started with pid [7726]
[ERROR] [1380277981.435323719]: Failed to load nodelet [/rgbd_image_proc] of type [ccny_rgbd/RGBDImageProcNodelet]: Could not find library corresponding to plugin ccny_rgbd/RGBDImageProcNodelet. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[FATAL] [1380277981.435695830]: Service call failed!
process[camera_rgb_optical_frame_tf-6]: started with pid [7738]
[FATAL] [1380277981.446783568]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1380277981.447004115]: Service call failed!
[openni_driver-2] process has died [pid 7651, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load openni_camera/driver rgbd_manager ir:=camera/ir rgb:=camera/rgb depth:=camera/depth __name:=openni_driver __log:=/home/dina/.ros/log/f9767520-275c-11e3-b82a-e006e61ca148/openni_driver-2.log].
log file: /home/dina/.ros/log/f9767520-275c-11e3-b82a-e006e61ca148/openni_driver-2*.log
[debayer-3] process has died [pid 7675, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/debayer rgbd_manager image_raw:=/camera/rgb/image_raw image_color:=/camera/rgb/image_color __name:=debayer __log:=/home/dina/.ros/log/f9767520-275c-11e3-b82a-e006e61ca148/debayer-3.log].
log file: /home/dina/.ros/log/f9767520-275c-11e3-b82a-e006e61ca148/debayer-3*.log
[rgbd_image_proc-4] process has died [pid 7708, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load ccny_rgbd/RGBDImageProcNodelet rgbd_manager __name:=rgbd_image_proc __log:=/home/dina/.ros/log/f9767520-275c-11e3-b82a-e006e61ca148/rgbd_image_proc-4.log].
log file: /home/dina/.ros/log/f9767520-275c-11e3-b82a-e006e61ca148/rgbd_image_proc-4*.log
```

Any ideas of why this is happening or any clues of how to fix it?
Or even if you thing there is a better way to make the mapping of the room without using ccny_rgbd_tools.

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84171/fail-to-load-nodelet/) by [sigmaduarte](https://answers.ros.org/users/7181/sigmaduarte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The errors says "Could not find library corresponding to plugin ccny_rgbd/RGBDImageProcNodelet"

The usual cause of this error are that the library has not been compiled. If you're on a remote machine, make sure that the remote machine has the package installed and it has been compiled. (Note the package which needs to be compiled is ccny_rgbd not ccyn_rgbd_tools)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1